# For loop iterating over os.remove throws error

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a list of files I want to remove with full paths, I'm trying to use os.remove, however it throws an error:

```
for item in zip(file_list):
    os.remove(item)

TypeError: remove: illegal type for path parameter
```

I checked the output from my list and it's as follows:

```
for item in zip(file_list):
    print(item)

('/home/user/directory/file1.ext')
('/home/user/directory/file2.ext')
('/home/user/directory/file3.ext')
```

If I manually try to remove the file, it works:

```
python
import os
os.remove('/home/user/directory/file1.ext')
```

So I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong from my debugging attempts or the [os docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). Apologies if this is a simple oversight, I am still learning the basics!

Comment: '/home.user/directory/file1.ext' here is a typo? Because is different from '/home/user/directory/file1.ext'. Is not the same path. You have home.user here.

Comment: The result after zip includes `$(...)` - I bet os.remove is confused by it. Don't `zip` file_list and see what happens.

Comment: What is file_list? And why are you calling zip on it?

Comment: The [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator of ***tuples***, so the error is as expected, given that `os.remove` requires a string argument.

Comment: `os.remove(item[0])` instead. But, this is not how you should do it. if its in a list just iterate on that instead. So,`for item in file_list:`

Comment: @Dan Yes - fixed in OP, thank you.

I'm using $: to denote the STD out, will remove as it's confusing!

And finally, file_list is ['/home/user/directory/file1.ext','/home/user/directory/file2.ext','/home/user/directory/file1.ext']

Comment: @scharette Perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Returns an iterator of tuples

So in your case `item` is a tuple and not a string.

Either remove the call to `zip` (preferred solution if you don't need it):

```
for item in file_list:
    os.remove(item)
```

or use `item[0]` to access the first element of the tuple which should be your file path:

```
for item in zip(file_list):
    os.remove(item[0])
```

Comment: Perfect, that's done the trick!

Just for future reference, is there a better way to iteratively call a function on all items in a list than the for x in zip(list) method used above?

Comment: Yes, do not use `zip`. I'll edit my answer to provide example.

Comment: Thanks to @scharette - I think my for statement should actually read:
    for item in list:
        os.remove(item)